# How do I update JSON data every 10 second in Sveltekit 1.0?

Tags: svelte, fetch-api, onmount

Need to convert code from old sveltekit to new sveltekit 1.0.

I used to used `onMount`, `onDestroy`, `setInterval` to re-fetch data, but I think it is deprecated in sevltekit 1.0.

**index.sveltekit (old version)**

```
<script>
import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte"; 

let listH = [];  
let listH_interval = [];    
onMount(async function getData() {  
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
listH = await response.json();   
listH_interval = setInterval(getData, 74000); 
}); 
onDestroy(() => clearInterval(listH_interval)); 
</script>

<pre>{JSON.stringify({listH}, null, 2)}</pre>
```

**+page.sveltekit (v1.0)**

```
<script>
import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte"; 

    export let data;
    const { listH} = data;
</script>
<pre>{JSON.stringify({listH}, null, 2)}</pre>
```

**+page.js (v1.0)**

```
<script>
onMount(async function getData() {  
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
listH = await response.json();   
listH_interval = setInterval(getData, 74000); 

}); 
onDestroy(() => clearInterval(listH_interval)); 
</script>
```

I know +page.js doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setInterval and clearInterval.

```
<script>
import { onMount, onDestroy, setInterval, clearInterval } from "svelte";
export let data;
const { listH } = data;
</script>
```

Move the onMount and onDestroy functions from your page.js file to page.svelte, and update them to use setInterval and clearInterval functions.

```
<script>
import { onMount, onDestroy, setInterval, clearInterval } from "svelte";
export let data;
const { listH } = data;

let listH_interval;

onMount(async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/");
  listH = await response.json();
  listH_interval = setInterval(getData, 74000);
});
onDestroy(() => clearInterval(listH_interval));
</script>
```

Also: you can remove the index.sveltekit file (it is not needed in the new version of SvelteKit)

Comment: When I tried, I got 500 internal error. I pasted above code to +page.svelte.

Comment: Have you checked that the URL you are trying to fetch data from is correct and that the server is responding properly?

Comment: yes, url is correct.